# LiveCycle ES 8.2 PDF dynamic population in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, livecycle

I want my website to generate dynamic reports in `PDF` format. I found out recently about `Adobe liveCycle Designer ES` which create editable fields inside of `PDF` document. 
 Does anyone knew if it is possible to create a empty template in `Adobe liveCycle Designer ES` and for example populate it with `php form` values dynamical after user clicking a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can create PDF template in LiveCycle Designer, however in order to populate it with data in a automatic manner you need a Adobe LiveCycle server with Forms module. It has some web services that combines data and template together. You should now that it is quite a costly solution.

[More details about generating pdf with data via web service you can find here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/000592.html#1548552)

Comment: Its more then I need to decide to look for another solution. Thank You Poliglot